# Angularjs parent index in ng-repeat limitTo filter not working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an array of letters say "A to I" which I want to divide into batches of predefined size and print in the following format. I am trying to use nested ng-repeat to achieve the same -

A B C D

E F G H

I

But instead it is always printing the first four letters all the three times, as shown below -

A B C D

A B C D

A B C D

Can somebody please point out what I am doing wrong? Any alternative/better solution is also appreciated.

Following is my code -

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Nested ng-repeat</title>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-beta.18/angular.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    .solid-border {border:solid; margin: 2px; width: 100px;}
    .inline-display {display: inline}
  </style>
</head>
<body ng-app="limitToExample">
  <script>
    angular.module('limitToExample', [])
      .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
        $scope.batchSize = 4;
        $scope.letters = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I'];

        $scope.getNumberOfBatches = function(){
            var res = Math.ceil($scope.letters.length / $scope.batchSize);
            var arr = [];

            for(var i = 0; i < res; i++) {
              arr.push(i);
            }
            return arr;
        };

        $scope.getNextBatchSize = function(batchNumber){
            if(batchNumber * $scope.batchSize < $scope.letters.length){
                return $scope.batchSize;
            }
            return $scope.batchSize - ((batchNumber * $scope.batchSize) - $scope.letters.length)
        };
      }]);
  </script>
  <div ng-controller="ExampleController">
    <div class="solid-border" ng-repeat="i in getNumberOfBatches()">
      <div class="inline-display" ng-repeat="letter in letters | limitTo: (($parent.$index + 1) * batchSize) | limitTo: (0 - getNextBatchSize($parent.$index + 1))">
          {{letter}}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a filter to divide your array in a row-column manner wherein the number of rows is equal to your `batchSize`

[**PLUNKER**](http://plnkr.co/edit/62M3GDa0PGBRg3RpCLq7?p=preview)

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
.filter('partition', function() {
    return function(array, size) {
        var newArray = [], i, next;

        for(i = 0; i < array.length; i = next) {
            next = i + size;
            newArray.push(array.slice(i, next));
        }

        return newArray;
    };
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div ng-repeat="row in letters | partition:batchSize track by $index">
    <span ng-repeat="letter in row track by $index">{{letter}}</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you this works. Actually I already found a solution using filter but this one is simpler and clear unlike mine which is a  little confusing.  But I am still wondering what is wrong with my initial approach using limitTo filter.

Comment: Quick update - Since my application updates the list in ng-repeat on user interaction, I had to remove the "track by $index" part before using your solution. When I did this, the digest cycle started to go in an infinite loop since you are returning a new array every time from the filter and since my list is quite large. I finally had to get rid of the filter, implement the same code in controller and create a new scope variable to store the batches, to get it working.

Comment: Hi thanks for this solution @Vince, should I inject `$partition` in my controller ? thanks